# How to use variable and move variable at the same time?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, move, order-of-execution

Let's assume we have the following code:

```
struct some_class : parent
{

    some_class(::other_class oth) :
       parent(some_function(oth.some_property), std::move(oth))
    {}

};
```

Of course construction results in undefinied behaviour (crash in my case), since c++ does not specify execution order. But then, how can I retreive the property before the movement? I cannot change the parent.

Comment: There is no undefined behavior here. `std::move` is just a cast to an rvalue reference. The culprit is the code in the constructor of `parent`. Since that isn't shown, it's hard to know what might work.

Comment: True, not really undefined, but definitely unexpected. Depending on which compiler you use, `some_function` is called on either the "original" `oth` or a "moved-from" `oth`. If `oth.some_property` is e.g. an `std::string`, then it either contains its original value or is empty.

Comment: What is `some_function` doing with its parameter?  `std::move` doesn't actually do anything on its own.

Comment: @Darhuuk That is only the case if `parent`'s constructor takes the second argument by-value, rather than by-reference. Otherwise nothing problematic happens until the body of `parent`'s constructor executes.

Comment: @walnut True, I was assuming that's the case. Otherwise this question would make little sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a delegating constructor:

```
struct some_class : parent
{

    some_class(::other_class oth) :
       some_class(some_function(oth.some_property), std::move(oth))
    {}

private:
    some_class(const ::Foo& foo, ::other_class&& oth) :
       parent(foo, std::move(oth))
    {}
};
```

Comment: Hmm. If I merge your answer with that of Darhuuk, I'll get a delegated constructor of some_class(const ::Foo& foo, ::other_class&& oth), which may actually be the answer I seek?

Comment: I'd find this to cause quite unexpected behavior if that 2nd constructor is called directly. I'd make that a private constructor.

Comment: I thought you couldn't modify `parent`?

Comment: @Dekakaruk your proposed edit wont compile, the delegating constructor takes a reference not an rvalue reference for a reason

Comment: @AlanBirtles my bad, fixed.

Comment: @anatolyg I've fixed the typo, should work better now

Comment: It's generally good to explain answers instead of just saying "try this". Discussed here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/509868

Comment: @anatolyg I think the code is pretty self explanatory? I do explain that its using a delegating constructor?

Answer (score 3):

Create a helper function to construct the parent where you can add sequencing:

```
parent make_parent(::other_class &&oth) {
    auto sf = some_function(oth.some_property);
    return parent(sf, std::move(oth));
}

some_class(::other_class oth) :
    parent(make_parent(std::move(oth))
{}
```

Comment: You can even write it with a lambda.

Comment: I imagine that a lambda would look horribly obfuscated in this context. In addition, you need some space in your code to put comments about what is going on here, anyway.

Comment: Almost works, but what if the constructor is protected and possibly the class non-copyable-nor-movable?

Answer (score 1):

As you note the issue is due to unspecified execution order. 
You can get rid of the undefined behavior by making `parent` take an object by rvalue reference instead of by lvalue. That way it gets a reference to an existing object and that object's data in memory won't actually have been moved. I.e.:

```
struct parent {
   parent (int thing, SomeProperty && some_property) { /* Do stuff. */ }
};
```

In this case it doesn't matter when `std::move` is executed on `oth`. It's data won't actually be moved into another object, since `parent` expects an rvalue reference. So even if `std::move` is called first, your `some_function` (which I'm assuming is taking `oth` by const lvalue reference) will have a proper object to work with.

The main drawback here is that parent now always requires in rvalue. So you can't pass it an object without moving it. Which means that if you have an object you don't want to get rid of, you'll first have to explicitly make a copy of it. I.e:

```
other_class wantToKeepThis;
auto foo = parent(wantToKeepThis); // Doesn't compile.
auto foo = parent(std::move(wantToKeepThis)); // Object gone, don't want this.
auto foo = parent(other_class(wantToKeepThis)); // OK, copied, parent gets rvalue.
```

Comment: I'd prefer not to change the parent, but your idea of using && alongside the idea of constructor delegation by Alan Birtles might be the answer.